# Error converting LWUIT project to Codenameone

Tags: lwuit, codenameone

I'm trying to convert an existing LWUIT project to Codenameone. I copy the sources and resources to a new j2me project I add the codename1.jar to the libraries of the project  then I fix the imports in my source and every thing seems to be ok but when I run the midlet I get this:

`No Class Def Found Error java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError`  `com/codename1/impl/ImplementationFactory`

is there a missing thing in the library?
I'm using codenameone as a library ,i dont use the designer.
am I doing some thing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Codename One sources from SVN and compile the MIDP port of Codename One to build a native J2ME application.

Comment: But now I have a problem with Image.createImage(String path) it shows no ':' in url exception How can i fix this?

Comment: I suggest you accept this answer and open a new question with the full details you are getting and what you are trying to open.